# Google Drive Api Integration in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api

``I am creating  asp.net 4.0 web application. I have created ClientID and Client Secret . I want to authenticate user and upload  file in google drive from my web application.
I have checked this link :-
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs.

But it is related to console application. 
How can we upload our file using ASp.net web application?

Here is code sample

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{String CLIENT_ID = "XXXXX";
    String CLIENT_SECRET = "YYYYY";

    // Register the authenticator and create the service
    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        Authenticator = auth
    });

    File body = new File();
    body.Title = "My document";
    body.Description = "A test document";
    body.MimeType = "text/plain";

    //my code start


    //my code end

    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/GoogleDrive/document.txt"));
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
    request.Upload();


    File file = request.ResponseBody;
    Response.Write("File id: " + file.Id);
    Response.Write("Press Enter to end this process.");}
private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
{
    // Get the auth URL:
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

    // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
    Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
    Console.Write("Authorization Code: ");
    string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
    return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Its just an C# code you can use the same for asp.net.You may need to change a few things like console.write to Response.WriteLine() etc..Or did you try this code and you got any error?

Comment: yes, i am getting an error of authorization(401). While it is executing code request.Upload().

Comment: post the code that you tried..401 usually comes when you have supplied wrong credentials.

Comment: i posted the code , please check.It is showing error of 401 in  "request.Upload();" this line